# Max area quadrilateral inside a convex

Tags: algorithm, optimization, convex-optimization, convex

I'm having trouble finding an efficient algorithm for the next problem: Given a convex polygon of size N (when N > 4), find a quadrilateral which is inclosed in the polygon with a maximal area

You can solve it in O(N^4) by choosing 4 points on the polygon and calculating the area (and finding the max area one) but I'm looking for a more efficient solution

Comment: What is a "convex"? Do you mean a convex polygon?

Comment: yes a convex polygon , thank you I edited that

Comment: Do you select the vertices of the polygon? Please describe your algorithm in more detail.

Comment: I don't see how your O(N^4) solution would work. Choosing 4 points on the polygon does not necessarily give a square.

Comment: so filter out those who aren't quadraticals, please notice I'm looking for a quadratical and not a square

Comment: So all four corners of the square have to touch the polygon? Only at corners or is it also possible on the edges?

Comment: it's not possible that a max area quadratical will have a point on the edge of the convex because you could increase the area by moving the point that is on the edge and keeping the other points on the same places

Comment: There are some recent (2017) papers about this that prove an earlier approach was incorrect, it doesn't look that easy to extract a *working* algorithm from them however

Comment: If your polygon is a rectangle that is not a square, how would you place a square inside it that touches only at corners?

Comment: you can assume that  N > 4

Comment: I guess I still don't fully understand what you are asking. Can't you just chose two corners of the polygon and check if the square with this diagonal also has its other two corners on the polygon? That would give O(N^3).

Comment: [This problem?](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00681.pdf) (oops; maybe harold meant the same link)

Comment: @Henry I already wrote that but i'll write it again, please notice I'm looking for a quadratical and not a square, those are 2 completely different things

Comment: Ok, so what is a "quadratical"?

Comment: quadrilateral* sorry, edited that

Comment: @sascha looks like it, thank you very much, i'll read it. could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @sascha it looks like the writer of the paper described an algorithm with lower complexity which fails to find the true answer